# Robot Framework: Issue in checking for a text after span

Tags: xpath, robotframework

In Robot Framework, I am trying to check whether "XXX" exists in the source code as follows:

```
<button class='btn-aaa'>
<span class='bbb'>
XXX
</button>
```

I tried with the following codes but they failed:

```
Page Should Contain Element | //button/span/following-sibling::text()="XXX" 
---> Valid xpath but encountering error in Robot Framework with error message "InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //button/span/following-sibling::text()="XXX" because of the following error: TypeError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The result is not a node set, and therefore cannot be converted to the desired type." 

Page Should Contain Element | //button/span[@class='bbb']/following-sibling::contains(text(),"XXX")
---> Invalid xpath

Page Should Contain Element | //button/span[@class='bbb']/following-sibling::[contains(text(),"XXX")]
---> Invalid xpath
```

Could anyone please suggest the proper way to check for "XXX" using the right xpath in Robot Framework?

The following are the info of the tools utilised:

- robot framework version 3.0.4
- Selenium Version 3.14.1
- Selenium2Library Version 3.0.0
- Python 3.6.6

---

Edited:

I really appreciate that all of you are trying to help. Thank you very much.
I will try to provide as much info as I can, so that you can help me as well.

I tried with:

```
//button[normalize-space()='View Data']
```

Unfortunately, it found nothing.

There are other buttons but there is only one with the text "View Data".

Here are more detailed code. I don't know whether it will help comparing with the simplified one mentioned earlier:

```
<button class="btn btn-submit float-left" type="button" onclick="return doActionParam('https://www.blabla.com/blabla',{op:'viewBla',blaId:'wxyz', activeTab:getActiveTabName()})">
<!--groupParent.-->
<span class="bongobongo"></span>
View Data
<button>
```

Hope the info is more helpful this time. Thanks again.

Additional Info:

Browser: Mozilla Firefox 62.0.3 (64 bits)

Comment: Is there a reason you are specifically using xpath as opposed to css  selector?

Comment: It's just for standardisation by sticking to xpath as the entire test automation script is using xpath. Feel free to suggest if there is a better way.

Comment: Ok cool, I would suggest using the css path rather than the xpath. The xpath is explicit and if the project is in development will constantly have to be changed. The css path is much less brittle.

Comment: Thanks, KeithMc18. I will try that out.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this xpath: `//button[normalize-space()='XXX']`

Your test should be: `Page Should Contain Element  //button[normalize-space()='XXX']`

Comment: Thanks for the proposed solution. I tried but it failed detect the element. I have edited my question with more detailed code and info.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your page does not contain a span with the text "XXX". What it actually has is "newline, XXX, newline". Also, neither the span nor the button has a sibling (and thus, no following-sibling).

You can ignore the whitespace surrounding the text with `normalize-space`. For example, the following works for me when I create an HTML document identical to what you have in your question:

```
Page should contain element  //button[normalize-space()='XXX']
```

This should work on the updated example in your code, by simply replacing `XXX` with `View Data`:

```
Page should contain element  //button[normalize-space()='View Data']
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I am a noob. Unfortunately, the suggested solution does not work as the xpath cannot be detected. I have edited my original question with more detailed info and code. I hope it will help in answering my question better.

Comment: @user1172930: my code works for your new example too. There must be more that you aren't telling us. If you take _exactly_ the html code you posted and use _exactly_ the xpath in my answer (replacing XXX with View Data), it should work. There's no reason why it wouldn't. I've tested with chrome and firefox on linux and osx.

Comment: You are absolutely right, Bryan. By right it should work. I have created a simple page using html containing the code above. The xpath suggested actually worked. Now I am also cracking my head on why it does not work on the actual code (I am not the developer). The actual code is messy. Not sure what is the blocking factor. By using ridiculous xpath like this actually works: form/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/button

Comment: I tried this and the button can be found: //form/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/button. However, when I tried this it failed: //form/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/button[normalize-space()='View Data']. What could possibly be the issue here?

Comment: The solution provided actually works but it's just not working at the webpage I am working on. I have decided not to waste time. So I use //form/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/button instead.